# Earliest hook to reliably get $post/$posts

Tags: filters, hooks, actions

What's the earliest possible action I can hook into where I'll be able to access the global `$post/$posts` variables on both the front and back ends? I've tried looking through [the Codex reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Action_Reference), [Adam Brown's reference](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/actions) and skimming through the source several times but haven't had much luck finding a good one.

`pre_get_posts` is too early; Using `posts_selection` doesn't work if you want to make a second get_posts() call during the callback; and `template_redirect` doesn't run on the admin side. `the_post` might be earlier than `template_redirect` for the front end, but it also doesn't run on the back end. Ideally I'd want something that runs right before `get_post()/get_posts()` returns, but I'm not seeing anything like that.

I've used the `the_posts` filter in the past, but I'd prefer an action because it's more technically correct.

Right now I'm just hooking in twice; once using `template_redirect` for the front end, and again using `admin_xml_ns` for the back end. I don't really like that, though, since the my logic isn't semantically related to either of those hooks, and it seems like this is a very common need and there should be a hook like "post_get_posts" (ala `pre_get_posts`) that works on both sides.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For all admin pages and front end pages except individual post edit screens (`wp-admin/post.php`), `'wp'` is the most reliable hook for getting the global values.

http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/nav.html?wp-includes/class-wp.php.source.html#l486

You can see there that it fires immediately after `WP::main()` fires `WP::register_globals()`. The problem with using things like `post_results` and `get_posts` is that it will run every time you make a query for posts. `'wp'` only fires in the function `WP::main()`, which is what WP core uses to run the page's main request query.

For post edit screens, it looks like the first hook you can use reliably would be `'add_meta_boxes'`. You would just need to make sure that you're on a core page when hooking in, although it does pass the global `$post` object as the second argument (the first being the `$post_type` of the current post).

Answer (score 5):

`posts_results` is the filter on the raw query result. see line 2627 in `wp-includes/query.php`.