# Help With A Reverse Pagination Plugin

Tags: plugins, pagination

I saw this presentation about why pagination on the Internet is weird. https://speakerdeck.com/u/espylaub/p/pagination-on-the-internet-and-why-its-weird
It inspired me to try and make a WordPress plugin to do just that. Here's what I've got so far...

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Reverse Pagination
Description: Pagination starts higher and goes lower for more consistent archive page numbering.
Author: Russell Heimlich
Version: 0.1
*/ 


function reverse_pagination_pre_get_posts($t) {  
     $q = $t->query_vars;
     if ( empty($q['order']) || ((strtoupper($q['order']) != 'DESC') && (strtoupper($q['order']) != 'ASC')) ) {
        $q['order'] = 'ASC';
     }

     $t->query_vars = $q;
}

function reverse_pagination_wp() {
    global $wp_query;
    $wp_query->posts = array_reverse($wp_query->posts);
}

if( !is_admin() ) {
    add_action('pre_get_posts', 'reverse_pagination_pre_get_posts');
    add_action('wp', 'reverse_pagination_wp');
}
```

I hook into the `pre_get_posts` action and switch the order query var to ASC instead of the default DESC.

Next I needed to reverse the order of the posts returned so they are in reverse chronological order. I chose the `wp` action for the reasons outlined in this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22768

So things are looking good so far. I just need to fix the first page. Right now if my blog has 50 pages and there is no `paged` parameter set the blog index page will show my very first post instead of the latest post. I need some logic to check if `paged` isn't set to set it to the same value of `$wp_query->max_num_pages` for that query.

I also need to disable the canonical redirect that removes /page/1/ from the URL and tweak the `get_pagenum_link()` function so it returns /page/1/ for `get_pagenum_link(1)` http://hitchhackerguide.com/2011/02/12/get_pagenum_link/

If there is anything else that can be added to make this plugin better please speak up! Thanks and I hope we can make this happen by working together on it.

Answer (score 1):

This function will give you a url for a page number without stripping the url for page 1:

```
function get_pagenum_link_full($pagenum = 1, $escape = true ) {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $pagenum = (int) $pagenum;
    $request = remove_query_arg( 'paged' );
    $home_root = parse_url(home_url());
    $home_root = ( isset($home_root['path']) ) ? $home_root['path'] : '';
    $home_root = preg_quote( $home_root, '|' );
    $request = preg_replace('|^'. $home_root . '|i', '', $request);
    $request = preg_replace('|^/+|', '', $request);
    if ( !$wp_rewrite->using_permalinks() || is_admin() ) {
        $base = trailingslashit( get_bloginfo( 'url' ) );
        $result = add_query_arg( 'paged', $pagenum, $base . $request );
    }
}
```

Modified from the original code for `get_pagenum_link()` as defined here http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/link-template.php.source.html#l1408

`get_pagenum_link_full(1);` will give you something like `http://www.url.com/category/page/1` depending on your permalink settings.