# Reverse ordered pagination on home page

Tags: pagination, frontpage

Use on the blog reverse pagination. The question arose. How to make a home page is not the first? Need to break the link `Home` = `First page` and make a connection `Home` = `Last page`.

Home should be the last. For example on a blog with 20 pages: Opening the site at `httр://www.example.com` I get to the home page. And this the same page at the address `httр://www.example.com/page/1/`

I want to do the opposite: `httр://www.example.com` opens page 20
 (`httр://www.example.com = httр://www.example.com/page/20/` ).

For example like this http://izismile.com. Home is the last, not the first.

Comment: Can you just describe your question more clearly?

Comment: are you want to change order of your posts?

Comment: no. see example    this http://izismile.com. Home is the last, not the first.

Answer (score 0):

The default order of posts is date descending.

To reverse it for home page you could hook into [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) and for `is_home()` query set `order` parameter to `ASC`.

Note that that pages would still go from 1 ascending, they will just have posts on them in opposite order. I don't think actually reversing order of pages is easily doable.

Comment: the fact is that the very reverse pagination is done. Entries go as expected. Code took here http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60547/help-with-a-reverse-pagination-pluginit works fine.There was only one problem. Home starnitsa this page / 1 /, and the need to page/20 /How to make a home page www :/ / example.com/page/20 /??? sorry for my english. Use the program interpreter

Comment: If you are interested found a solution.  wp-includes/query.php the file in block  / / Paging in the variable $page gave meaning max_num_pagesgot what he wanted. main = page/20 (or page/21....999 depends max_num_pages)  ie reverse pagination work was completely wrong.