# When and Where is `global $post` Set and Available?

Tags: posts, globals, oop

Usually when people think of the `global $post` object it's assumed that it's actually set whenever you enter [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). I started to play around with how early I could actually call `global $post` which looks like:

before `wp_head()` in most `header.php` files

before `template_redirect` action

after `plugins_loaded`

So my question is, what's the earliest I have access to `global $post`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Global `$post` var is set by [`WP::register_globals()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/register_globals/) method.

It is called by [`WP::main()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp/main/) method, on its turn called by [`wp()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp/) function that is called when [`wp-blog-header.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-blog-header.php) is loaded.

If you look at the [graph](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/35541) **@Rarst** built, on the left, you can see where `wp()` function is called.

In terms of hooks,  global post variable is set just before [`"wp"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp/) hook runs, so that is first hook to be safely used to check it.

Comment: Wow that graph... That's awesome.

Comment: note as regards edit post admin pages: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22768/76440

Answer (score 0):

the $wp global object is initialized in wp-class.php,

I just read an [article that explains the wp init process](http://theme.fm/2011/09/wordpress-internals-how-wordpress-boots-up-2315/),

I think the global $post variale gets defined and can be called after wp-setting.php...

let me know, regards