# $wp_query initiation?

Tags: wp-query, templates, archives

I'm wondering when does WordPress initiate its main query which sets the global `$wp_query` and enable us to use `has_posts()` and `the_post()` functions. If I create a page using archive template, how does it know how to set its query?

I'm looking at the *archive.php* in one of the WordPress default themes. They have an archive page but it just calls `get_header()` and `has_posts()`, so that means the query is already set. So WordPress routes the url to use the custom post type param in the URL?

If I choose to make custom archive pages, where do I modify the main query? In the new archive template file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [Rarst](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/847/rarst) has a [very famous answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/26622/7355) where he lays out [the load process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpHRx.png). Looking at this graph whenever [`wp-blog-header.php`](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-blog-header.php) gets loaded it calls function `wp()` which sets up many of WordPress globals like `$post` and `$wp_query`. ( [Secondary Reference](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/165736/7355) by User [Gmazzap](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/35541/gmazzap) )

That's the technical side of things but it looks like the core of your questions is creating your own custom archive pages. WordPress has a [Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) which allows you to create [custom archives](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-post-types) for things like Custom Post Types.

Another common way to modify the main query is to use a [Hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/) in your functions.php file called [`pre_get_posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_posts/). This will let you modify the query object before WordPress actually pings to database to get the information which makes it very easy to modify The Loop with different settings. An example could look like this which would modify The Loop to show 20 posts instead of the default 10:

```
function wpse_265733( $query ) {

    // Don't run on admin
    if( $query->is_admin ) {
        return;
    }

    // Run only on the blog page
    if( is_home() ) {
        $query->set( 'posts_per_page', 20 );    // Set posts per page to 20.
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_265733' );
```

Comment: So my main question really is how WordPress parses the url and from that it sets a few params to go fetch templates and set query vars. I found a really good post https://roots.io/routing-wp-requests/ explaining the WordPress routing basics. So from I've understood so far, template files themselves may not set the query (and probably shouldn't?) We'll need to have add hooks to modify/set the main query. Also I wish there's some articles out that explains how WordPress is parsing urls to retrieve custom post types or taxonomy terms and then setting query according to these functions.

Comment: @TurtleTread I'm the author of that article. As written there, WordPress stores rewrite rules, that are a map from URLs to query arguments. For CPT and custom taxonomies, when you register them, WP creates rewrite rules for them, so the query is set in the same way. After query has been set, WP loads `template-loader.php` that based on the type of query loads the related template. You can see the source code for it here: https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/template-loader.php#L44-L74

Comment: @TurtleTread So when templates are loaded, a query is _already_ set from URL (that query is known as "main query") otherwise WordPress wouldn't know which template to load. If you create queries in templates, those are _secondary_ queries that might be used to show different posts. To change the main query you should use `pre_get_posts` hook as suggested in this answer.

Answer (score 3):

After plugins and theme functions are loaded, WordPress parses the incoming request into query variables, by going through the list of rewrite rules to find a pattern that matches the request.

There are a number of default rules for the built in types- pages, various archives, single views, pagination, feeds. You can add your own rules or endpoints manually, or register new content types which can auto-generate all those rules for your custom content.

Once the request is converted to query variables, the query is run. In many cases, the results of the query are what determine which template gets loaded.

Then of course the template is loaded, and everything is good.

So that said, there are a number of actions and filters available to let you modify things at every step. To see a more detailed view of the process and what some of those things are, have a look at the [Action Reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request).

The simplest and most common method is the [`pre_get_posts` action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts). This exposes the query variables and lets you modify things before the query is run. See [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for a reference of query vars.

If that doesn't satisfy your needs, have a look at the [`request` filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/request), which allows more radical query manipulation, as it runs directly after query var extraction, before WordPress has made any decisions about the type of request that's happening.

Comment: A lot of the themes have the templates for archives, but to use these, we need to either follow the url  convention so that they set the correct query. Or we need to somehow pass a WP_Query object to start the loop? So these templates do not set the query themselves? which does make sense. But where is the common place to pass the query based on URLs? If we want to filter the query with post_type but use the same template, do we handle that in theme functions file or maybe a plugin that parses the url and determine the query params?

Comment: @TurtleTread It's a little difficult to get what you're referring to but you can modify the query in `pre_get_posts` based on `$_GET` vars in the URL.

Comment: @TurtleTread I think `pre_get_posts` is what you're after. Typically archives are per-post type, but it's not uncommon to modify the default posts page query to do things like add additional post types, or filter on meta data. But yes, if a template utilizes the main query and regular loop, it is using the query that has run before that template was loaded.